# Django manipulate model fields programmatically

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to use the following base model to allow our team to add a `unique_reference` field to various models where required, using custom attributes (namely `prefix`, `length` and the `field_name` of the field).

is there a clean and agreeable way to achieve what I am looking for with Django?

```
class UniqueFieldModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.prefix = getattr(self.Meta, 'unique_reference_prefix')
        self.unique_ref_length = getattr(self.Meta, 'unique_reference_field_name',
                                         settings.UNIQUE_REFERENCE_MAX_LENGTH)
        unique_ref_field_name = getattr(self.Meta, 'unique_reference_field_name')
        unique_reference_field = models.CharField(
            max_length=self.unique_ref_length,
            blank=False,
            null=False
        )
        setattr(self, unique_ref_field_name, unique_reference_field)
        super(UniqueFieldModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.unique_reference:
            prefix = getattr(self.Meta, 'unique_reference_prefix')
            self.unique_reference = \
                self.gen_unique_value(
                    prefix,
                    lambda x: get_random_string(x),
                    lambda x: self.objects.filter(unique_reference=x).count(),
                    self.unique_ref_length
                ).upper()
```

I would say that one possible way would be to normalise the name of the `unique_reference` field over all models.

But it is suboptimal, as it will require a lot of refactoring, and will be semantically incorrect in some cases.